# How would you describe the lava in a lava lamp?

Tags: adjectives

I can only think of the word morphing but that is pretty boring and not exactly what I am looking for. I want to talk about the way that they seemingly levitate as it changes and absorbs itself while simultaniously breaking apart

Comment: *This is not an answer to the OP question, but just worth knowing*. In 1996, Landon Noll from Silicon Graphics and his cryptology team   developped and patented a system based on Lava lamps. The principle was to digitalize the shapes got from six lamps with a camera. Images were then hashed through a cryptographic algorithm (SHA-1) to give the seeds for generating pseudorandom numbers.

Comment: Sounds like *blobulating* to me. Or maybe *amoebafacation*?

Comment: Consider *blobbing*. It is defined in *OED* as "To produce blobs or bubbles". I could find some [relevant examples in Google Books](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22blobbing%22+%22lava+lamp%22) also.

Comment: Isn't it called a lava lamp specifically because it kind of looks like lava? I'd call it lava-like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm partial to ***"transmogrify"***, or it's heftier noun version, ***"transmogrification"*** - meaning "to change or alter greatly and often with grotesque or humorous effect" - per [MW-O](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transmogrify)

What astonished me was how old this word is:

Origin of TRANSMOGRIFY (MW-O):

> origin unknown
>
> First Known Use: 1656

Answer (score 2):

How about the adjective **amorphous**?  Lacking a defined shape, or having a shape that shifts.

Answer (score 0):

In a lava lamp, the floating luminous waxy substance is called a **blob**. (Another similar word is a *glob*, a colloquial word derived from *globule*). Blob can also be used as a verb and **blobbing** can be used as a participial adjective derived from the verb *blob* (or can be used as a present participle verb).

The noun definition of *blob* from [*OED*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/20337?rskey=iM2I4c&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid):

> A drop or globule of liquid or viscid substance. Also *figurative.*

The related verb definitions of *blob* from [*OED*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/20339?rskey=iM2I4c&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid):

> *intransitive.* To rise in a bubble or bubbles.
>
> *intransitive* ? To produce blobs or bubbles; to ‘flop’ in the water.

Here is an example with the noun *blob*:

> The lava lamp glooped its way into pop culture history with its ascending and descending blobs of wax. - *[gizmodo.com](https://gizmodo.com/the-psychedelic-physics-behind-the-lava-lamps-hypnotic-5890103)*

Here is an example with the adjective *blobbing*:

> On a table beside a blobbing orange lava lamp were framed photos.
>
> <sub>*[Life Support](https://books.google.es/books?id=LbvVAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA98&dq=%22blobbing%22%20%22lava%20lamp%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia24vXiMH4AhUD_xoKHcRLD0sQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22blobbing%22%20%22lava%20lamp%22&f=false)* - By Candace Calvert</sub>