# A term that captures translate and rotate

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms, terminology, legalese

From this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333978/one-word-rotatable-translatable-scalable), *transform* (or *linear transform*) was the consensus.

Say I have a broad phrase like:

> Travel of the fluid urges a _____ of a partially-submerged bob.

Forgiving the lack of context, the use of "of a", and the reason behind being so intentionally broad, the _____ must comprise obviously at least *rotation* and/or *translation*. For example, "linear transformation" may cause a judge to scratch their head (or think of linear travel at worst!).

> Travel of the fluid urges a [translation] of a partially-submerged bob.
>
> Travel of the fluid urges a [rotation] of a partially-submerged bob.
>
> Travel of the fluid urges a [movement] of a partially-submerged bob [wherein such movement may be characterized by an algebraic linear-transformation]. ??? <-- too prolixic!

Note: I'm not allowed to simply say "rotation or translation" because that closes the possibilities from a legal point of view (e.g. zig-zag is forever excluded).

How could I fill in the ____?

- Displace doesn't include rotation.
- Movement alone could be a twitch or a jerk, and doesn't imply rotation.
- Articulate implies a joint.
- Escapement strongly implies only rotation.
- ???

Comment: Affine transformations include rotations and translations. But if you're concerned that a judge will misconstrue "linear", good luck with "affine".

Comment: That’s pretty clever. Affine never came to mind. It feels a lot like sheering though, or how I fix my photos that I took from an angle.

Comment: I've provided the answer _blobbing_ to the question [How would you describe the lava in a lava lamp?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/289452/how-would-you-describe-the-lava-in-a-lava-lamp/590771#590771) but it works for the floating waxy subtance in a lava lamp. It _might_ work for your context too but it would help if you clarify your context. Is a _bob_ a solid object? Does _translation_ mean changing the form or state here, what is happening exactly? You could also neologize "transrotation" which has current usage already per google search.

Comment: Boom. https://patents.google.com/?q=%22transrotation%22&oq=%22transrotation%22 yields "in a manner known in the art, such as, for example, worm gears and transrotation transfer means." Please reify your answer.

Comment: Does ship motions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_motions answer your question?

Comment: How about "transposition"?

Comment: As you want to be as general a possible (is this a patent application?) I can't see your problem with "movement". A rotation is, very definitely, a movement even if it's constrained by a fixed axle, for instance millstones rotate around a fixed axle but, when they are rotating, they are certainly in motion. If you want to exclude twitches or jerks you could specify "a smooth movement".

Comment: I would also suggest "induces" rather than "urges" since the bob is entirely passive and has no volition. To me you can only "urge" a sentient being to do something for itself. For instance you can "urge" a dog to chase a ball, your child to get out of bed or a dementia patient to eat but you can only "cause" an inanimate object to move by "inducing" movement in it. No matter what you say to a paving slab it won't get up of its own accord.

Comment: The bob is *free* to move. It has 6 degrees of freedom and there are no physical constraints to it's displacement or orientation. Engineers go to great pains to keep the two separate because linear momentum and rotational moment are independent conserved quantities.

Comment: @BoldBen "urge" is a legalese term used in the case of a direct transfer of mechanical energy. "Induce" as in "to induce vomiting" hides a middle mechanism of muscle contractions; I cannot "urge" vomiting, but I can "induce" it. Again, legalese term (yes, for a patent). :)

Comment: @BoldBen "a smooth motion" --> yes, a nice phrase. Presently, I'm using " predetermined and regular motion of generally rotation and translation" but I'm repeating it dozens of time!

Answer (score 1):

*Transrotation* is a neologism (a portmanteau of *transfer/transform/translate* + *rotation*) that appears in academic and formal contexts; and one can find examples in *[Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22transrotation%22&rlz=1C1VDKB_enCA994CA994&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFt678h9j6AhUVK30KHZt6DnMQ_AUoAXoECAMQCw&biw=1536&bih=746&dpr=1.25)* and *[Google Patents](https://patents.google.com/?q=%22transrotation%22&oq=%22transrotation%22)*. The term appears to be mainly used in geology; but one can find usages in other fields like materials science also.

Here is an example usage:

> Spinler *et al.* (2010) carried out a very detailed analysis of deformation in the eastern Transverse Ranges (Joshua Tree area) using elastic block models to analyse new campaign-style GPS data. They compared four different models for the area, incorporating varying amounts of vertical-axis rotation from zero to 15° Myr–1, which were to a large extent specified by the chosen block geometry. The models involving rotation are, in effect, bookshelf slip or ‘**transrotation**’ models.
>
> <sub>J. P. Platt, T. W. Becker, Kinematics of rotating panels of E–W faults in the San Andreas system: what can we tell from geodesy?, Geophysical Journal International, Volume 194, Issue 3, September 2013, Pages 1295–1301, https://doi.org/10.1093/gji/ggt189</sub>